# loading flash files (.swf) webview in android

Tags: android, flash, webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load an SWF into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview)

I have a .swf file and I want to open it into a webview and also want to play flash games loaded there in the webview. How do I do that?

[image]

I am getting swf file in encoded form in webview instead of a clock.

Comment: can you give me code of load swf file in android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think You should implement setPluginsEnabled method.

example

```
String url ="file:///android_asset/hoge.swf";

WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);

wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I am getting data in encoded form insted od image... please see this image                                                                  http://www.freeuploadimages.org/images/p1mm7d9vkwmsnpyqat4.png

Comment: how to do this in lolipop onwards apis