# Play Flash in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, flash, plugins, webview, android-webview

How can I play Flash content in a WebView?
Any tutorial?

Comment: Do you have a webpage embedding a Flash component in your app?

Comment: By the way, have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview

Comment: I have a webview, I enabled java and plugind but nothing

Comment: Please, can you post your code ?

Comment: oh, I solved it! by adding this --> android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
to the code, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `setPluginsEnabled(true)`:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Related:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=552988
- http://androidforums.com/application-development/171895-play-local-swf-file-flash-webview.html

Comment: oh, I solved it! by adding this --> android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
to the code, thanks for your help

Comment: I put both  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" and setPluginsEnabled(true) my problem solved.

Comment: i think i need something else ... all steps already done, but the result still empty.... i wonder what else should i do then? @Samuel....