# Play SWF in Android 4.2

Tags: android, flash, android-webview

I am trying to play one SWF (flash) file in my application deployed on Android 4.2.2. When I save the file on file system, and open it with browser, it works well. But when I try to open the same in webview in my application, it does not play the swf. It just shows a broken file type small image. I have searched stack for the proper answer but any answer I found here is very old and not working for me, this must be because of the non-support of swf on new android version. I have also tried after installing the old flash player, but it shows just the first frame of swf.

Comment: I have installed the Adobe air player on the device and the flash is working on it, though the display quality is a bit low. Anyone know some better way apart from installing the adobe air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Credits to [joren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92259/joren): [Load an SWF into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview)

Comment: Method got deprecated then removed. Now use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34743447/603270

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an embedded flash player that plays the SWF rather than simply embedding the SWF. I haven't flashed around in a while now and certainly don't do it on Android but that's my immediate thought. (EDIT - The other answer here nailed it: plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like installing Adobe Air player on device is the only solution. Please suggest if any better way is available.