# Display html page which has some .swf object with it

Tags: android, webview, flash

I want to display html page which has some .swf object with it.

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

These settings failed.

Comment: Have you tried using `webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);` ? More info you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Flash is not supported by Android, or any other mobile operating system for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash is now at version 17, and as Android support stopped at version 11.1

when Flash was supported on Android, it required to enable plugins support on the WebView. But it's not supported anymore since Android 4.1 (Jellybean). And Android 4.4 devices use a new WebView implementation which is garanteed to not support any plugin.

If you want this to work, you have to install Flash on an older device with Android 4 or lower.