# How to play swf flash files in android Application?

Tags: android, flash

How to play swf flash  files in android .Android doesnt support it . Is there any way to play flash files in android app then please tell me. Thanks

Comment: You can take a look to my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40200606/5013103

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge `.swf` files are no more supported in 4.3 and higher versions.
If you still want to use it then you need to add plaugins to your app which supports `.swf` files. or there are some swf players are available you can use them also [https://play.google.com/store/search?q=swf+player](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=swf%20player)

Comment: which plugins are used to do same

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview . hope it helps you.

Comment: ok, are you getting a cube like symbol in your webview? plz post your code whatever you tried.